# Gray infestation along the veins on tomato leafs

Tags: tomatoes

See attached image. Something gray spreads from older leafs through the veins on tomato plants. Stems and upper side of the leaf look normal. It doesn't seem impacting the plant though. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Tomato Odema/Edema[tomato Edema and why](https://www.ces.ncsu.edu/depts/pp/notes/oldnotes/gp3.htm)..[tomato Odema leaves](http://negreenhouseupdate.info/sites/negreenhouseupdate.info/files/images/tomatoEdema1.jpg)

Sorry for the short version but running off to catch horses!!
Back later...